# How do I change what the digital crown scrolls, if there are multiple scrollable Views?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

In my case there is a Picker capsulated in a ScrollView. In the beginning the Picker isn't visible, so I wish that the Crown would scroll the ScrollView until the Picker is visible and selected via touch. 
What it does right now, is trying to scroll within the Picker and changes its value, when the crown is rotated. The user has to scroll down a bit, so the Crown selects the ScrollView to scroll.

Here a simplified code version of mine:

```
ScrollView {
      ButtonView(data: self.data) //is longer than the screen.height

      Spacer()

      PickerView(data: self.data) //includes the Picker

      Spacer().padding(.top)

      NavigationButtonView(data: self.data)
}
```